# How to declare OnClick() function within a for loop and pass different values each time? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, antd

I'm trying to create a list of React components.
Each component contains a button, which needs to have an onclick event.
This onClick event needs to pass some variables which change with each iteration of the outer loop.
However the value of these varaibles is not different for each component. I believe they all pass the values from the final loop iteration.

How do I get around this?

I've looked at some other solutions using closure and .map() etc. But I cant seem to apply them properly to this.

```
performSearch = (query, searchIndex) => {

var resultsComponents = [];
var currentTeam = "";
var currentID = null;
var playerName = null;
var totalPoints = null;
let tempState = Object.assign({}, this.state)

//Iterate through the list of players
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.playerElementsData.length; i++) {
  //if the current players name contains the users search term
  if ((this.state.playerElementsData[i].first_name.toUpperCase() + " " + this.state.playerElementsData[i].second_name.toUpperCase()).includes(query.toUpperCase())) {

    //find the club the player belongs to
    for (var j = 0; j < this.state.teamsData.length; j++) {
      if (this.state.teamsData[j].id == this.state.playerElementsData[i].team) {
        currentTeam = this.state.teamsData[j].name
      }
    }

    //store the players details in variables. These need to be passed to the OnClick function
    currentID = this.state.playerElementsData[i].id
    playerName = this.state.playerElementsData[i].first_name + " " + this.state.playerElementsData[i].second_name
    totalPoints = this.state.playerElementsData[i].total_points

    //create a component containing this players details and add it to the list to be rendered
    resultsComponents.push(
      <div>
        <Card title={playerName} 
        extra={<Button type="primary" shape="circle" icon={<PlusOutlined />} onClick={() => this.selectPlayer(searchIndex, currentID, playerName, totalPoints, currentTeam)} />} >
          <p>{currentTeam} </p>
          <p>{" Points : " + totalPoints}</p>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//render the list of components.
ReactDOM.render(resultsComponents, document.getElementById("results" + searchIndex));
```

};

Comment: use `let` instead of `var`, `let` is block scoped and will preserve each value in a separate execution context.

Comment: @GabrielLupu It will still be scoped to outside the forloop. Why not move the variable to inside the loop?

Comment: I don't know how this translates to reactJS, but my preferred method is to add a data-attribute to the button itself. Like `data-index='Variable'` etc. Then in the onclick handler, I would refer to the element itself and grab the data attribute value like `element.dataset.index`. This way the values are adding to the buttons themselves when they are generated.

Comment: Using let didn't help. I think the function uses the values available when it is clicked rather than when the component is created. Which would be the values after the loop has finished.

Comment: Change currentID = this.state.playerElementsData[i].id to `let currentID = this.state.playerElementsData[i].id` and see if you get different id in the callback fn?